# Compound Interest Calculation (Years + Months)

Tags: finance

My question is with regards to the calculation of "Compound Interest". I have the formula below where I would get an answer to the total value of the investment over a period of "years".

- $A$ = Future value
- $P$ = Principal amount
- $R$ = Annual interest rate
- $N$ = Number of times compounded each year
- $T$ = The number of years the money is invested for

$$A = P\left(1 + \frac{R}{N} \right) ^{NT}$$

So for example if I have the following:

$P = 5,000\$$

$R = 5\%= 0.05$

$N = 12$ (Compounded monthly)

$T = 10$ years

The answer for **A** will be equal to **$8,235.05**

My question is how can I derive the equation above to account for the period of years and months? So, for example, how would I calculate $A$ if I had $T$ being equals to $T$ = $10$ years + $6$ months?

I think that the answer to the equation derivation is shown below but I'm not sure:

$$A = P\left(1 + \frac{R}{N}\right)^{N(10 + 1/2)}$$

Can anyone confirm if my calculations are correct?

Comment: Yes, 10 years and 6 months is 10.5 years.

Comment: Yes, your calculations are correct provided the exponents are as shown in the question (as edited by me). @bharb's assertions about $T$, the number of years, needing to be a multiple of $N = 12$ are based on a mis-reading of the definitions of the various symbols.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yup! Too much math, too little thinking here. Comment deleted! +1